# How do you tune segment size in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

The default value of `maxMergedSegmentMB=5000` perfectly works for databases smaller or slightly larger than 5GB.

It is recommended to increase `maxMergedSegmentMB` when the database grows larger.

I wonder what is the rule of thumb for tuning this value for very large databases?

For example, if a database is 1TB, is it practical to have 1 segment of 1TB or 200 segments of default 5G? In practice, it should be something in between, but how do you decide about it?